# Hive 'Load' command not considering Field Delimiter

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to create a hive table using Hive CLI on Hortonworks Sandbox as well as on C3 Cluster. In my 'CREATE TABLE' command, i specify the following:

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0010' ​
```

and then i load the table using the 'LOAD' command. ​This is giving a correct Hive Table in Sandbox but on C3 cluster, this appends all the fields in the first column and gives NULL values for the rest of the columns. 
Please help me to resolve the following issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-13434) with unicode literals that is suppose to be fixed in version 2.1

Use decimal or octal notation instead.

```
... fields terminated by '\020'      (Octal)
... fields terminated by '16'        (Decimal)
```